# Change Windows 7 app taskbar icon color

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application and I want to add a cool little visual to its thumbnail on the Windows Taskbar.

I know that you can have the thumbnail display a Progress Marquee-style thing, but how do we just change the color of it?

[image]

I'm not talking about changing the color of the icon, but the color that's behind the icon. Is this even possible?

Any code, documentation or anything to get me on the right track will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. even the color that it is highlighted with is taken from the icon itself (the predominant color).

Comment: I just noticed that, @Nacereddine - I wonder if it is possible to fake a highlight while my application is in "Lock down" mode. It's not something that I want to do but it will definitely be worth it if I can do it.

Comment: you could use the [red highlight](http://i.imgur.com/FmMnY.png).

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do! Do you have any resources for this? Links or anything?

Comment: @Nacereddine: If memory serves, that's known as color hot-tracking, and the hot-track color will only show when the icon is hovered while having a window.

Comment: @BoltClock The highlight color shown in that screenshot is the one used to indicate progress (an API that was added in Windows 7) : Red for error, yellow for a paused operation and green when everything is normal. So tl;dr : you don't need to hover the icon for the color to show up.

Comment: @Nacereddine: Oops, I forgot to mention I was referring to your first comment on the question. I'm aware of the taskbar progress overlay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the TaskBar APIs available in the [Windows API code pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)

```
// This will highlight the icon in red
TaskbarManager.Instance.SetProgressState(TaskbarProgressBarState.Error);
// to highlight the entire icon
TaskbarManager.Instance.SetProgressValue(100,100);
```

Please note that this API was intended to indicate an error with a progressing operation (file copy, etc..)

Comment: The corresponding nuget package: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows7APICodePack-Shell/